# CodeDeploy appspec.yml pas variable to after-install.sh

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, aws-code-deploy

I'm passing $ENV variable from appspec.yml to after-install.sh via git actions. But during AWS CodeDeploy after-install.sh not reading variable from appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /aws
    destination: /var/www/domain.com  # Specify the destination path on the EC2 instance

hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: aws/scripts/after-install.sh  # Path to script
      runas: root  # User to run the script as
      timeout: 300  # Timeout for the script execution
      environment:
        ENV: development # later I'll write it using git actions to deploy on development/staging/production
```

after-install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "Environment: $ENV"
```

How to pass variable from appspec.yml to after-install.sh?